# Событие по клику на QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qtextbrowser

Есть папки с текстовыми файлами, отображаемые в `QTreeView`, при нажатии на файл создаётся `QTextBrowser` с содержимым файла. Их может быть несколько, и я хочу реализовать выделение этого файла в древе элементов при нажатии на его `QTextBrowser`.

Как будет лучше и проще вызвать функцию `set_focus_on_tree` и можно ли это сделать не выводя элементы в отдельные виджеты и классы, сохранив текущую архитектуру?

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,QTreeView, QTextBrowser


class StandardItem(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, txt=''):
        super().__init__()
        self.setEditable(False)
        self.setText(txt)


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.treebox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
        treeModel = QStandardItemModel()
        rootNode = treeModel.invisibleRootItem()
        data_directories = os.listdir('data')
        for directory in data_directories:
            dir_name = directory
            directory = StandardItem(directory)
            file_list = os.listdir(f'data/{dir_name}')
            for file in file_list:
                file = StandardItem(file)
                directory.appendRow(file)
            rootNode.appendRow(directory)
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.text_manager)
        self.treeView.setModel(treeModel)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.treebox.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setLayout(self.treebox)

    def text_manager(self, val):
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(val)
        if val.data().endswith('.txt'):
            with open(f'data/{val.parent().data()}/{val.data()}', 'r') as file:
                self.textbrowser = QTextBrowser()
                text = file.read()
                self.textbrowser.setText(text)
                tblayout = QVBoxLayout()
                tblayout.addWidget(self.textbrowser)
                self.treebox.addLayout(tblayout)

            def set_focus_on_tree():
                self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В подклассе `TextBrowser` добавьте `сигнал` и
переопределите метод `mousePressEvent`

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QTreeView, QTextBrowser
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, pyqtSignal                  # +++


class StandardItem(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, txt=''):
        super().__init__()
        self.setEditable(False)
        self.setText(txt)


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class TextBrowser(QTextBrowser):
    mySignsl = pyqtSignal(QModelIndex)
    
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.val = val
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self.mySignsl.emit(self.val)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.treebox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
        
        treeModel = QStandardItemModel()
        rootNode = treeModel.invisibleRootItem()
        
        data_directories = os.listdir('data')
        for directory in data_directories:
            dir_name = directory
            directory = StandardItem(directory)
            file_list = os.listdir(f'data/{dir_name}')
            for file in file_list:
                file = StandardItem(file)
                directory.appendRow(file)
            rootNode.appendRow(directory)
            
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.text_manager)
        
        self.treeView.setModel(treeModel)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.treebox.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setLayout(self.treebox)

    def text_manager(self, val):
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(val)
        if val.data().endswith('.txt'):
            with open(                                         # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                f'data/{val.parent().data()}/{val.data()}', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                self.textbrowser = TextBrowser(val)    # - QTextBrowser()
                self.textbrowser.mySignsl.connect(self.set_focus_on_tree)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                
                text = file.read()
                self.textbrowser.setText(text)
                tblayout = QVBoxLayout()
                tblayout.addWidget(self.textbrowser)
                self.treebox.addLayout(tblayout)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def set_focus_on_tree(self, val):
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(val)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]